# How do I parse DBObject to case class object using subset2?

Tags: mongodb, scala, subset, implicit-conversion, salat

Does anyone know how to parse DBObject to case class object using **[subset2](https://github.com/osinka/subset2)** ? Super concise documentation doesn't help me :(

Consider following case class

```
case class MenuItem(id : Int, name: String, desc: Option[String], prices: Option[Array[String]], subitems: Option[Array[MenuItem]])

object MenuItem {
  implicit val asBson = BsonWritable[MenuItem](item =>
    {
      val buf: DBObjectBuffer = DBO("id" -> item.id, "name" -> item.name)
      item.desc match { case Some(value) => buf.append("desc" -> value) case None => }
      item.prices match { case Some(value) => buf.append("prices" -> value) case None => }
      item.subitems match { case Some(value) => buf.append("subitems" -> value) case None => }
      buf()
    }
  )
}
```

and I wrote this parser

```
val menuItemParser: DocParser[MenuItem] = int("id") ~ str("name") ~ str("desc").opt ~ get[Array[String]]("prices").opt ~ get[Array[MenuItem]]("subitems").opt map {
  case id ~ name ~ desc_opt ~ prices_opt ~ subitems => {
    MenuItem(id, name, desc_opt, prices_opt, subitems)
  }
}
```

It works if I remove last field `subitems`. But version shown above doesn't compile because `MenuItem` has field that references itself. It gives me following error

```
Cannot find Field for Array[com.borsch.model.MenuItem]
    val menuItemParser: DocParser[MenuItem] = int("id") ~ str("name") ~ str("desc").opt ~ get[Array[String]]("prices").opt ~ get[Array[MenuItem]]("subitems").opt map {
                                                                                                                                                 ^
```

It obviously doesn't compile because last `get` wants `Field[MenuItem]` implicit. But if I define it for `MenuItem` wouldn't it be pretty much copy-paste of `DocParser[MenuItem]` ?

How would you do it elegantly ?

Comment: Is your code producing a compilation error or are you just not getting the behavior that you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am an author of Subset (both 1.x and 2).

The [README](https://github.com/osinka/subset2/blob/master/README.md) states that you need to have `Field[T]` per every `T` you would like to read (it's under "deserialization" section)

> Just a side note. Frankly I don't find very logical to name a deserializer for `MenuItem` to be `jodaDateTime`.

Anyway `Field[T]` must translate from vanilla BSON types to your `T`. BSON cannot store `MenuItem` natively, see native BSON types [here](http://bsonspec.org/)

But certainly the main problem is that you have a recursive data structure, so your "serializer" (`BsonWritable`) and "deserializer" (`Field`) must be recursive as well. **Subset** has implicit serializer/deserializer for `List[T]`, but they require you to provide those for `MenuItem` : recursion.

To keep things short, I shall demonstrate you how you would write something like that for simpler "case class".

Suppose we have

```
case class Rec(id: Int, children: Option[List[Rec]])
```

Then the writer may look like

```
object Rec {
  implicit object asBson extends BsonWritable[Rec] {
    override def apply(rec: Rec) =
      Some( DBO("id" -> rec.id, "children" -> rec.children)() )
  }
```

Here, when you are writing `rec.children` into "DBObject", `BsonWriteable[Rec]` is being used and it requires "implicit" `Field[Rec]` in turn. So, this serializer **is** recursive.

As of the deserializer, the following will do

```
  import DocParser._

  implicit lazy val recField = Field({ case Doc(rec) => rec })
  lazy val Doc: DocParser[Rec] =
    get[Int]("id") ~ get[List[Rec]]("children").opt map {
      case id ~ children => new Rec(id, children)
    }
}
```

These are mutually recursive (remember to use `lazy val`!)

You would use them like so:

```
val dbo = DBO("y" -> Rec(123, Some(Rec(234, None) :: Nil))) ()
val Y = DocParser.get[Rec]("y")
dbo match {
  case Y(doc) => doc
}
```

Comment: Alexander, just curious. Why there is no `BsonWritable` for `List[T]`in the library ?

Comment: `Seq[T]` is more generic and will be picked up for `List`. (if you need more information, read about covariance in Scala. Another good reading can be about "type classes")

Comment: Hmm.. It doesn't pick it up for `List` in my case. Same compiler error for missing `Field[List[T]]`.

Comment: See [this test case](https://github.com/osinka/subset2/commit/879a67a4b7c68294ac989a794c5d85ddf4e5ada3). If it doesn't help, please try to refine your compilation error to the smallest snippet and file an "issue" at GitHub